# Прибавление очков при соприкосновении с объектом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всех приветствую. Хочу попробовать написать простенькую игру. И на одном из этапов столкнулся с проблемой. При соприкосновении с объектом он исчезает и издаёт звук. Но мне ещё надо чтобы счётчик обновлялся. Как мне это сделать? Я создал Canvas и внутри него [поместил текст](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1keyZl6wjTSz4y9fXhasmayCAlkRSmTbZ/view?usp=sharing).
Прилагаю код для уничтожения объекта:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destroys : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audio;
    private void Start()
    {
        
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "bottle_green")
        {
            audio.Play();
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "coins")
        {
            audio.Play();
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно, это то, что Вы хотите сделать. Объявите public переменную `scoreText` и счетчик `scoreNum`, изначально равный 0. При соприкосновении увеличивайте счетчик и обновляйте значение на экране. Не забудьте в Инспекторе перетащить Ваш `Text` со счетом на соответствующее поле скрипта.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Destroys : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audio;
    public Text scoreText;
    private int scoreNum = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "bottle_green")
        {
            audio.Play();
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            scoreNum++;
            scoreText.text = "Score: "+ scoreNum;
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "coins")
        {
            audio.Play();
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            scoreNum++;
            scoreText.text = "Score: "+ scoreNum;
        }
        
    }
}
```

И еще я заметила, что у Вас одинаковые действия при соприкосновении с `bottle_green` и `coins`. Возможно, это просто ещё недописанная часть, возможно, это для того, чтобы было два эффекта при одновременном соприкосновении, а возможно, это можно объединить и записать функцию `OnTriggerEnter` так:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "bottle_green" || other.gameObject.tag == "coins")
        {
            scoreNum++;
            scoreText.text = "Score: "+ scoreNum;
            audio.Play();
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
}
```

Соответственно, этот счёт будет сбрасываться при перезапуске. Если Вам нужно постоянно хранить это значение, можно использовать базу данных или `PlayerPrefs`... Но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает. Что касается последней части - я пытался совместить, но не получилось, и я забил. Просто я профан в C# да и в Unity в целом

Comment: Рада, что получилось помочь. Успехов в изучении C# и Unity, это интересная область! :)

Comment: Спасибо) Вам тоже удачи)